# Is it possible to programmatically write to the <startup><supportedRuntime> setting in an app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I am writing a small "Configuration" library for some of our products. The idea is to construct an app.config file programmatically (typically using another program, at install time). I would like to be able to write a new setting into this field (to specify, .Net 3.5, .Net 4.0 etc.) Does anyone know if it is possible via the System.Configuration ConfigurationManager / Configuration API?

I can get the `Configuration` object by asking the ConfigurationManager to load a template file, then I get can the relevant section by

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = "C:\template.config";
Configuration myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var sec = myConfig.GetSection("startup") as IgnoreSection;
```

However, as shown above, all this gets you is an "IgnoreSection" which does not appear to be mutable or castable to some other underlying type.

The template file is a pretty empty config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Is my only option to write the current config out to disk (thanks Configuration API, no streams!) and then replace it with regex or XML?

Comment: Well, this is a strong chicken-and-egg problem.  The .config file is read *before* your program starts running, doing it later cannot have any effect.  It is also normally stored in a directory for which you do not have write access, like c:\program files.  So, basically, no.

Comment: It is not a chicken-and-egg problem. I do not want the program to re-write its own configuration file before it begins. I am trying to write a library to generate config files, something that will be done at install time. Made a slight edit to the question to clarify.

Comment: "myConfig" is a *very* misleading name.  Keep in mind that it is simply an XML file.  A snippet that shows you using OpenExeConfiguration() would be wise.